# execution of an .exe file from php

Tags: php, exec

I have written this program:

```
echo exec('hi.exe '.$file,$results,$status);
if ($status === 0)
{
    echo implode('<br/><br/>',$results);
}
```

hi.exe is generating all the output in the respective files present in the same directory (.exe file is working well), but the problem is whenever I run this .exe file from localhost in my browser, the browser keep loading and it does not show any output.

Why this is happening? Why is the browser getting so slow?

Comment: does your server have permission to run the file?

Comment: Any chance that hi.exe is falling into an infinite loop?

Comment: yes it does... because the program is executing and it is generating the respective files in the backend. but in frontend its not showing the output

Comment: How can we check that @Hernan? and how can i stop this hi.exe from not falling into an infinite loop? any suggestions?